# Android Studio does not allow creating raw folder

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio reports that the **Raw** folder already exists, but does not appear in the RES root, as attached image

[image: Image RES]

Comment: Click on the spinner above app structure and choose project instead of android to view full resources.

Comment: The procedure did not work.
I accessed through the explorer the RES folder and I noticed that the RAW folder was with the first letter in uppercase. After changing to lowercase, the folder appeared in the RES root of Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

If it is reporting it already exists, it may exist already. Try rebuilding the project.

If it doesn't work, open res folder in file explorer and delete the raw folder and create it again.

To create a raw folder, right click on `res → new → Android resource directory → Choose raw in resource type, and hit ok`.

Comment: The procedure did not work.
I accessed through the explorer the RES folder and I noticed that the RAW folder was with the first letter in uppercase. After changing to lowercase, the folder appeared in the RES root of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

By the Spinner

NameOfYourApp -> App -> src -> main -> res -> raw

I had the same problem, with this path